# oracle trigger execute DBMS_AQ gets insufficient privilege error

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-aq

I am using oracle 11.2.

Database users:

1. **AQADM** : user owns queues, and has *AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE*
2. **SCOTT** : jms user, has following privileges.

I have following stored procedure, which compiled OK. and it is invoked from trigger on table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE scott.PROC_JMS_ENQUEUE (NAME      VARCHAR,
                                          MESSAGE      IN VARCHAR)
AS
  msg                  SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE;
  queue_options        DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
  msg_props            DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
  msg_id               RAW (16);
  no_consumers_error   EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (no_consumers_error, -24033);
BEGIN
-- Ensure what is sent will be a JMS message
 msg := SYS.AQ$_JMS_TEXT_MESSAGE.CONSTRUCT ();
 msg.set_text (MESSAGE);

 --ENQUEUE
 DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE (queue_name           => 'aqadm.my_queue',
                enqueue_options      => queue_options,
                message_properties   => msg_props,
                payload              => msg,
                msgid                => msg_id);
  -- Without the following, the procedure will die if none
  -- Is listening for cache control
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN no_consumers_error
 THEN
  -- Output it in case, but otherwise swallow
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
     'No interested parties are listening to messages');
 END;
 /
```

I have following GRANT to user

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON AQ_USER_ROLE TO scott;
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_AQ TO scott;
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_AQIN TO scott;
--GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_AQJMS_INTERNAL TO scott;
--GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.DBMS_TRANSFORM TO scott;
GRANT EXECUTE ANY PROCEDURE TO scott;
```

When i execute above stored procedure, or update table that fires trigger code, i get following error:

```
exec PROC_JMS_ENQUEUE('Test Message','Dam');

ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQ", line 169
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.PROC_JMS_ENQUEUE", line 19
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

**EDIT:**
Here is privileges view, all are granted as SYS as SYSDBA
[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked when i grant following

```
GRANT ENQUEUE ANY QUEUE TO SCOTT;
```

[Oracle sucks on one consolidated documentation!](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96587/qmanage.htm)

Also, some reason GRANT has to be "direct" not via "role" in order to execute via PL/SQL Trigger or Procedure!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Usually when some code works for you when executed from sqlplus but does not work when executed from a trigger is caused by the same reason:

Users have privs. granted either directly (Type=Priviledge) or indirectly(Type=Role). When code is executed as a trigger, only direct priv. are available. ie. you do not have any grants from AQ_USER_ROLE. Check AQ_USER_ROLE definition (I think this role is deprecated anyway) and grant these privs directly to SCOTT.